# Understanding Numeric Datatype in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class

```
class vw_invoice_header(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "vw_invoice_header"
    tax_amount = db.column(db.Numeric)
    total_price = db.column(db.Numeric)
    invc_number = db.Column(db.String(40))
    term_code = db.Column(db.String(20))
    order_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    airway_bill = db.Column(db.String(40))
    inh_auto_key = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
```

Now I get a result from an oracle db as below

```
invc = vw_invoice_header.query.filter_by(inh_auto_key=20643519).first()
```

I'm trying to use the value below to get a nicely formatted price in my jinja2 template

```
"{:8,.2f}".format(invc.total_price)
```

This throws an error, AttributeError: type object 'Numeric' has no attribute 'lower'
I have no idea how to just print out this numeric :/  Im a newb to python been using it for a week.

Thanks
Cameron

Comment: Are the `db.column`'s in your code not supposed to be `db.Column`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two fields should be `db.Column` not `db.column` (note the capitalization). `db.column` creates a `sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ColumnClause` object whereas `db.Column` creates a `sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Column` object like you want.

```
class vw_invoice_header(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "vw_invoice_header"
    tax_amount = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    total_price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    invc_number = db.Column(db.String(40))
    term_code = db.Column(db.String(20))
    order_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    airway_bill = db.Column(db.String(40))
    inh_auto_key = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
```

Once you correct this, the `Numeric` datatype will behave just as you expect.

Comment: Thank you! - Always ends up being something simple