# mysql column does not reflect decimals as expected and instead rounds

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two columns that are intended to reflect latitude and longitude, and I've set them up based on the [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Numeric) as Numeric. However, in the database, the values are saved as whole numbers. I'm aware there have been several similar questions asked on SO ([A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420754/flask-sqlalchemy-numeric-type),[B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526826/understanding-numeric-datatype-in-sqlalchemy),[C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501459/decimal-datatype-is-rounding-the-values)), but the common suggestions have not worked for me. Specifically, in my class, I've specified two columns as shown below, with the expectation that my saved value would include 8 numbers, 6 of which are decimals.

```
xcoord = db.Column(db.Numeric(8,6),nullable=False)
ycoord = db.Column(db.Numeric(8,6), nullable=False)
```

Directly before I commit the values, decimals are passed as expected:

```
 activity = Activity(xcoord=req['data']['xcoord'],ycoord=req['data']['ycoord'])
    print(activity)
    print('pre-db commit') #results in 40.267299 and -74.618776
    db.session.add(activity) 
    db.session.commit()
    print('committed to db')
```

However, given the above syntax, in my table, this is saved as:

```
'xcoord': -75, 'ycoord': 40,
```

From my reading of the above sources/documentation, I'm under the impression that using Numeric is preferred, and setting the precision/scale should suffice for my interests. I've attempted variations of the arguments available, including decimal_return_scale=None and asdecimal=False to no avail. It's worth noting that using asdecimal=False results in a single decimal (ex. 75.0) but still doesn't yield the expected result of 6 decimal places. Thanks for reading this far, and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: And how your `db.Numeric(8,6)` is mapped on the MySQL table structure? It must be `DECIMAL(8,6)`.

Comment: Hi Akina, thanks for reviewing. Apologies if I'm confused, but I haven't assigned the MYSQL table structure anywhere. I've arranged the db connection entirely from my Flask server. Therefore, after configuring the sqlalchemy URI, I simply assigned the columns xcoord and ycoord in my db.Model as shown above. Let me know if there's any information or section of my code that would be helpful to clarify. EDIT: As a note, my db is functioning as expected elsewhere, ex. with several other columns, FKs, etc. in a functioning application.

Comment: Your Flask operators are mapped to some MySQL queries. Which results in some structure created in MySQL. Look what structure is created (connect to MySQL directly via command-line client and execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`), what datatype has the column in interest.

Comment: thank you so much! this helped me correct the issue - just had to alter the column type in mysql itself - really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with a similar issue in the future, this ended up being a result of the issue as suggest by @Akina. Specifically, because I'd previously created the table with these columns as Int type, they weren't modified appropriately to match my Flask operators. The syntax in my python script was appropriate, and when I ran the following in MySQL shell, the problem was resolved.

```
ALTER TABLE mytablename MODIFY COLUMN xcoord decimal(8,6)
ALTER TABLE mytablename MODIFY COLUMN ycoord decimal(8,6)
```